# Multiple buttons perform single one task Android

Tags: android, button

I need to perform a task whereby a user need to click on multiple buttons to perform a single task for example dialog box, image or toast.

I mean that clicking on more than one button in order to execute a task. It would be better to let the user know he or she has already clicked on the first button by highlight the button with a color. And when he or she click on the second or third button,highlight the button and it will execute the task like toast or dialog box .

Can someone assist me thanks.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.android.testing1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Button5" />

</RelativeLayout>


package com.example.android.testing1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import static android.R.id.button1;
import static android.R.id.button2;
import static android.R.id.button3;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button dodo = (Button) findViewById(button1);
        Button dede = (Button) findViewById(button2);
        Button dada = (Button)  findViewById(button3);
        Button didi = (Button) findViewById(button4);
        Button hehe = (Button) findViewById(Button5);


        If(dodo == true, dede==true, dada == true , didi=true, hehe=true);

        Then perform same task ike toast or dialog box  after click on all the five buttons
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any efforts?

Comment: So far no but i know it require if

Comment: It is not really clear what your question is.

Comment: i have posted some code below,

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting additional information as answer

Comment: What i mean is that do do i perform a task like dialog box or toast. Only after i can clicked on all the 5 buttons.

Comment: I mean that how can you achieve a same task after user have clicked on the all the 5 buttons

Comment: It would be better if you can also teach to highlight each button once it is clicked